# Capturing Mouse Cursor and Draw on Image Buffer c#

Tags: c#, directx, buffer, sharpdx, dxgi

I'm working on a screen recording application and I can capture the screen but without mouse cursor. I used DXGI, SharpDX and Media Foundation.

My question is. Is it possible to write the mouse cursor on image buffer so the the image buffer I sent to mediafoundation has already mouse cursor in it before it encode to a video? Saw lot of sample here how to include mouse cursor in screen capture but what they did is convert both image to bitmap and then combine both. I already tried that but performance is not good and cpu usage is so high and also fps is low. without cursor I can capture 60fps smooth. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible implement your task, but it needs copy some code from C++ on C#. In my project [Desktop Screen Capture on Windows via Windows Desktop Duplication API with Drawing of Cursor's Image](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116253/Desktop-Screen-Capture-on-Windows-via-Windows-Desk) you can find the suitable solution. It is based on using a special 
Direct3D11 texture - it is created with `MiscFlag` - `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE`. It allows GDI rendering on the surface via `IDXGISurface1::GetDC` and using of Windows function DrawIconEx for drawing cursor's image. The drawing of cursor is executed by Windows function and is done in context of video memory.

Regards.

Comment: I'm stack at  IDXGISurface1::GetDC. I cant find the wrapper of this code in SharpDX.

Comment: Why you can not find? Check link [SharpDX-DXGI API](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/dxgi/#api-Interfaces) - it has `IDXGISurface1<ul><li>GetDC</li><li>???</li><li>???</li></ul><p>The interface extends the by adding support for using Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) to render to a Microsoft DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI) surface.</p>`

Comment: found it thanks its now working